# Metathinking impossible without ordinary language?

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-mind, philosophy-of-language

Many years ago I read somewhere that metathinking is absolutely impossible without ordinary language (be it a natural language like English, or a constructed one like Esperanto). After this statement a very persuasive argument followed, however I am not able to reconstruct it at all, no matter how hard I try. Internet searches are of no help.

Can somebody present a persuasive argument defending the abovementioned view, or a refutation of it (in case I misremembered the whole thing)? This is **not** a homework question.

Comment: What is metathinking? Thinking about thinking?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee yes.

Comment: Is it possible that it is just difficult to communicate what metathinking could be like without language, without language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking about other thoughts requires a reference to something that cannot be present to consciousness.  If I make a reference to an apple, I can make that present to my consciousness through sheer imagination of its traits.  As studies of the behavior of the deaf without language indicate, this can go really far, and whole communities can live in pantomime for decades.  So thought itself does not require language.

But I cannot make a reference to a thought by imagining its qualities, retrieving the thought itself occupies the stream of consciousness, and thinking about it is not possible at the same time in the same way.

This last insight is not a theoretical assumption, or a deduction from the immediate nature of thought.  It is an observation based upon the descriptions of thought processes in early literature --http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/402276.The_Discovery_of_the_Mind and the subjective reports of people who acquire or re-acquire language late in life ---http://www.radiolab.org/story/91728-words-that-change-the-world/

The memory of a thought therefore has to be referenced obliquely, and so has to be labeled in some way, either by its relative temporal position, or by outright naming.

So, at least some of the furniture of language needs to be present for thinking about thought to be possible.  You need some internal notion similar to the pronoun.  The question then is whether that requirement already constitutes language, or not.

For me, it does.  At the point where you reference things abstractly, and not by recalling them, you have committed yourself to abstract symbolization.  Even if your language has only one word, meaning something like "what came immediately before this in my mind", it has vocabulary, which is used temporally to create narrative structure, and is no longer simply pantomime.

Comment: Some common sense, at last!

Comment: Is storing a thought-in-process in working memory therefore "language"?  Or if not, why then can I not have sheer imagination of the traits of my cognitive processes?

Comment: @RexKerr  Absolutely not, and the question is a totally unrelated to anything I said.  As far as we can tell, consciousness is singular temporally, it can task-switch, but it cannot truly parallelize.  So having a thought, and having thoughts about that thought requires the thought be symbolized or otherwise abstracted rather than present to consciousness.  Symbolization is the necessary component of language.

Comment: Of course I am considering only conscious thought.  Unconscious thought parallelizes freely, so your 'sense' or 'intuition' of ambiguity or difficulty that might enter consciousness without focus upon or elaboration of a specific other thought then becomes a counterexample, if you include that as thinking.  But I assume the OP did not mean to include it.

Comment: How do you symbolize something if your consciousness is consumed with the experience that you're having?  Aren't you too busy with being conscious of whatever it is you're conscious of?  You need _some_ sort of representation to work on, but why can't you work on stuff in working memory?

Comment: Labeling happens outside conscious experience, so the first question makes no sense.  And yes, working on the stuff in working memory is creating a symbolic reference.  And symbolization, pointing at something with a label and not an image, is what I am talking about as the basic first component of language.  To put it in computer terms, you cannot reference another process by stating it by value, you can only do so by pointing at it, and to my mind, if something cannot be accomplished without a pointer, it is using vocabulary, so it is language.

Comment: @jobermark: There is no difference between thought about thought and thought about an apple. An apple is not present to thought unmediated just as a thought itself. There is a complex process of identifying properties, categorizing, abstraction that need to happen for us to call an apple "an apple". What we refer to when we say "an apple" is not some immediate memory - what we refer to is a symbolic construction - whether there is a physical apple before me or not is irrelevant. All thought is symbolic in this way.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with Nakiya on this one: everything conscious is going to be symbolic if you go this route.  What is "sheer imagination of its traits" aside from symbolic processing?  Somehow it seems that for your argument to be arguing that there is anything unusual about metathinking, consciousness must somehow cripple its normal computational abilities when applied to itself, unless it invokes some special subconscious processing routines not normally applied to e.g. apples.  That doesn't seem parsimonious or supported by evidence I'm aware of.

Comment: @nakiya What *we* refer to is a symbolic construction.  We have symbolization, for millennia humans didn't, and we occasionally find humans without it -- feral children and isolated deaf populations.  the way they act indicates they think differently.  You can choose to ignore this data, or not.  But I am not going to.

Comment: @RexKerr Explain why given populations (the rural deaf in countries without the notion of sign language) exist for decades without developing the equivalent of a pronoun, if everything is always basically symbolic in consciousness.  Are they not conscious?  I think 'pointers' are a technology that we do not realize is a technology, and that it is not natural, just so ingrained in us that we cannot question it.

Comment: Not being able to hold something in your left hand when you are already holding another thing in your left hand is not 'cripling' your left hands natural abilities selectively.  Assuming consciousness can do the same thing without trickery is instead assuming it is naturally and automatically much more flexible than any other organic process.  I prefer to assume it is not, and that it is culture that makes our consciousness so flexible.

Comment: The real reason for taking this seriously is that it seems for most of human prehistory, we didn't symbolize.  And we should have some model of how those people existed, if we are ever going to talk about what we mean by 'human'.  Were they not conscious, in our sense, or was their experience made up more like an animal's?  I mean, we can give the technology of symbolization to an ape, or a smart enough dog, to me that means it is a trick, not an inherent feature.  But how did it arise, as a technology?  If you assume early humans were just like us, but stupid, you lose important perspective.

Comment: @jobermark  I'm not sure if you're replying to me, but if so this is tangential, not addressing my concern with your answer.  _You_ were the one who said "working on stuff in working memory is creating a symbolic reference", so unless you think the rural deaf have any working memory (?!) or, I guess, people with damage to Broca's and Wernicke's areas, it hardly matters.  Also, you surely grant that "thinking" can conclude something and then work on that, and I assume you agree that this can be non-linguistic, yet you reject that you can move from "thinking" to "metathinking" in this way?

Comment: "haven't any working memory", I meant, of course.

Comment: @RexKerr  I am done dealing with the counterexample that is not a counterexample.  Stop repeating yourself.

Comment: Your model of conscious thought seems somewhere between weak and just wrong. This kind of thing backs up the model of conscious thought I am working from: http://www.radiolab.org/story/91728-words-that-change-the-world/  Three aspects: 1) existence of deaf communities that work through pantomime but to not have pronouns. 2) The almost complete inability to describe life without language once one has language.  3) The ability to transfer labeling *as a technology* to isolated individuals the same way we can give it to chimpanzees, implying it is technology and not a natural feature of thought.

Comment: @RexKerr  I think maybe we are addressing different questions.  There is no reason, once one starts using variables and labels, that one cannot then do that unconsciously.  But if one lacks that technology completely, one cannot begin 'meta-thinking'.  I am talking about the limits on people completely incapable of language, not insisting that each individual act of someone with language needs to take place in a specific way.

Comment: Maybe we are, but as it stands this answer is highly misleading, in that you claim that there is something we can do with an apple ("sheer imagination") that we can't do with thought. But if it's all just neurons computing stuff (almost certainly is), and mutually exclusive representations use different neurons (largely true at least in the hippocampus), then the computational substrate doesn't need to care whether you got transient input from high-order sensory cortex or previous activity in PFC or anterior cingulate or wherever. So your answer turns into a very weird definition of "symbol".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19812/discussion-between-rex-kerr-and-jobermark).

Answer (score 0):

The argument is (presumably) flawed because there are counterexamples.

(1) If it is a psychological claim (i.e. specific to the details of thinking as done by humans), I do most of my thinking without explicit symbology or an internal narrative.  This includes evaluation of my own abilities and "thinking".  You can't easily examine my thoughts, but I bet most readers have had the very clear sense, unverbalized but equivalent to "this will be easy" or "this will be too hard for me", when it comes to some cognitive task.  That is a type of metathinking.

(2) If it is a computational claim, practically any recurrent network can do the job. You can build an associative network between sets of symbols *x<sub>i</sub>* and *y<sub>j</sub>* (which is "thinking") and have one of the y's trigger an estimate of the time of computation of the associative network which then feeds back into one of the x's on the next pass ("thinking about thinking").

There is some wiggle room to make the claim true if one defines "meta-" narrowly enough so that *only* expression of linguistic symbols counts as "meta" (or as "thinking").  But the claim is then basically a tautology.

Comment: " You can't easily examine my thoughts, but I bet most readers have had the very clear sense, unverbalized but equivalent to "this will be easy" or "this will be too hard for me", when it comes to some cognitive task. That is a type of metathinking." - that is not a type of metathinking. Metathinking is having an unsymbolized thought about the fact that you are thinking. Metathinking is _not_ having an unsymbolized thought about your capabilities to do something. Hell, even my cat can evaluate her capabilities to make a certain jump.

Comment: I'm not your downvote. It could be the jetlag, but I'm not sure if they are counterexamples because I haven't the foggiest what the OP means by metathinking or for that matter by "ordinary language" -- on at least some definitions of "ordinary language" I cannot imagine how it would be the language of any of our meta-thinking.

Comment: "You can't easily examine my thoughts, but I bet most readers have had the very clear sense, unverbalized but equivalent to "this will be easy" or "this will be too hard for me", when it comes to some cognitive task" - Aren't these examples of intuition rather than meta-thinking? Because meta-thinking implies it is directed, concious.

Comment: @user132181 - I'm not sure what your claim here is.  You are saying that unsymbolized thoughts about your prospects or progress on a thinking task are not "about the fact that you are thinking"?  I gave that example rather than simple qualia-of-the-fact-that-one-is-thinking because in evaluating your thought processes you are, presumably, thinking.  Why is evaluation of capabilities not thinking?  (It must not be, if evaluation of ability to think about things is not "thinking about thinking".)

Comment: @virmaior - Point taken--I also am not entirely sure what the OP means (especially about "ordinary" language--what is "extraordinary language" anyway?), but I thought I could cover enough of the possibilities to make the answer somewhat worthwhile.

Comment: @nakiya - Isn't evaluating the difficulty of a cognitive task directed?  (Or couldn't it be directed?  It may sometimes come unbidden.)

Comment: @RexKerr : Yes it is directed, but my point is, there's a trivialization or some sort of pattern matching going on if you get a hunch about something. The origin of this lies in past experience where the thought process actually took place. The question is whether you can have these "hunches" without some thoughts doing the work for you at a previous time.

Comment: @nakiya - How do you know any of that, or that it is different when linguistic brain regions get involved?  This isn't to say they're not _helpful_ but the question is whether they're _necessary_.

Comment: @RexKerr - Not sure what you mean by how I know any of that?. For a simpler example, think of memoization in programming. The processing is necessary, but once it has been done, we can use the result without resorting to computing it again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19757/discussion-between-nakiya-and-rex-kerr).

Answer (score 0):

Your argument can be reduced to remove the 'meta,' which makes it simpler to refute (but my answer will not directly refute it.  It will simply make an easier to think about question)

Metathinking, as you define it, is "thinking about thinking."  So we have requirement number 1 for metathinking:

- You cannot have metathought without thought, for metathought is thought about a thought.

Now we can bring in "ordinary language,"  a metathought is a thought, or metathought in general is a category of thoughts.  This has an interesting implication:

- If "ordinary language" is required for metathought, then there exists a category of thoughts which cannot occur without "ordinary language," or else metathought would be possible without language.

**I would start from this question: are there thoughts that cannot occur without "ordinary language?"**  The dialogue regarding this question would form a framework for defining several words we are stumbling over, such as "ordinary language" "metathought" and arguably even "thought" itself.  It might even have to define "impossible!"

This sort of dialogue will be essential, because the answers are many.  For instance, there is still a debate as to whether *any* thought can occur without language.  A belief in that philosophy will quickly reduce your original question to triviality.

Answer (score -1):

This is fairly straightforward. It all depends on whether you agree that thinking is symbolic (using language). Meta-thinking is just an instance of thinking in general, i.e. the object of thought is thought itself. there's no qualitative difference between thinking and meta-thinking as far as I am concerned.

So, it all boils down to "what is thinking?". If you subscribe to any theory that says thinking is impossible without a symbolic (linguistic?) system, then the answer to your question is yes. Then again, why do you qualify "language" as "ordinary language?"

The above is, I feel too simplistic. This does not analyse thought. I'll try to elaborate my limited understanding on this:

Any object in thought is Platonic (ideal, transcendental, abstract, perfect). There are also universals in thought (As Hegel says) like here, now, this, etc. Can we think "now" without language? We cannot, because the operation of language is operation of thought itself (abstraction from being) - When we think "This table is round", we are manipulating abstractions and universals. If we want to characterize zebras, we have to make a generalized abstraction. The word "zebra" is an arbitrary consensus. The thought zebra is a composite thought about an "horse-like animal with black and white stripes in body". So, the thought "zebra" is a composite arrived at by recursive application of thoughts. They exists in opposition to each other but also support each other. There is no good without bad, etc. But because an individual zebra does not represent the Platonic ideal, the word "zebra" is needed. And this is the relationship to thought. We think in ideal Platonic terms. Language enables us to do so.

Comment: But metathinking is not about ordinary things, it is about thinking.  One can reference an apple by its characteristics, but if you have referenced a though by its characteristics, does that not constitute a real symbol, in a way your memory of an apple does not?  It is a reference to something that cannot be constituted in memory at the same time as the reference is used, since the mechanism of symbolization is already occupied.  So it is an abstract word.

Comment: care to elaborate why downvote?